# How can I make a Coordinates Object Dynamic in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I'm using lines a module for Titanium Appcelerator to draw lines. In lines you just need 2 Object with coordinates to draw a line (start and end point).

I want to modify the start/end point object with a 'touchmove' event, However I'm fairly new with JavaScript and I just can't figure it out the right way to do it.

```
var lines = require('com.lines'); //<< Import lines module

var attrib = { 
    color:'red',
    touchEnable:true,
    thickness:20
};

var from = {x:20,y:100}; //<< Start Point Object Coordinates
var to = {x:200,y:100}; //<< End POint Object Coordinates
var lineOne = lines.createLine(from, to, attrib); //<<Creates lineOne var with attributes
win.add(lineOne); //Draw the line.
```

I have no problem moving the whole line using the lineOne variable, however as I said I can't found a way to modify the objects dynamically.

thanks!

UPDATE - After Josiah's suggestions I was able to successfully modify the "to" variable, however the line would redraw itself with the original "to" value no matter what. I'm either using the setTo method incorrectly or I need something else to update and redraw the line..

```
var attrib = {
    color:'red',
    touchEnable:true,
    thickness:20
};

var from = {x:20,y:100}; //Insert touchMoveFunction <<-- Here! 
var to = {x:200,y:100};
var lineOne = lines.createLine(from, to, attrib);

function drawline(e){
    win.add(lineOne);
};

alert(to);

var lineOne = lines.createLine(from,to,attrib);

var buttonPosition = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'CLick.Me!',
    bottom:0
});
win.add(buttonPosition);

buttonPosition.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    to = {x:200,y:300};
    lineOne.setTo(to);
    drawline();
    alert(to);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach an event listener for [`touchmove`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-touchmove) to the window (or whatever view container that is holding the lines) and then refresh, or whatever is necessary for the lines to change, heres a little example:

```
var lineOne = lines.createLine(from, to, attrib);
win.add(lineOne);
win.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    win.remove(lineOne);
    var touchX = e.x;
    var touchY = e.y;
    var to = {x:touchX,y:touchY}; 
    lineOne = lines.createLine(from, to, attrib);
    // Add a new line
    win.add(lineOne);
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks Josiah, I'm having troubles updating the "to" variable, apparently Im either using the setTo method incorrectly or there is no setTo method in titanium. I used a couple of alerts to verify the "to" variable is being updated, and it is working. Problem is the line re-draw itself in with the original "to" position no matter what.

Comment: I've never used the lines module, so I was guessing on what you have to do. Try the above, just remove the old line, and then redraw it.